# Change width of div as orientation of mobile change in magento

Tags: jquery, magento, jquery-mobile, magento-1.7

I am working on magento mobile theme.

I want to set width of li on the basis of mobile screen.

For that I am using

```
  <script>
        jQuery(function() {
        var width= jQuery(window).width();
        jQuery(".press_li").width(width*0.75);
       });      
 </script>
```

Its working. But when orientation changes then width didn't change. For that I am trying to use jQuery-mobile but when I include jQuery then other jquery stops working.

Comment: Using media queries would work much better.

Comment: I have to calculate the width of li on the basis of mobile screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next code to fix your problem

```
function setPositions() {
    var width= jQuery(window).width();
    jQuery(".press_li").width(width * 0.75);
}
$(document).ready(function(){setPositions()})
$(window).resize(function(){setPositions()})
```

Look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/q7FqJ/

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is [function scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).
Your `width` variable is within the scope of the anonymous function bound to the document ready state.

As fix, you can either repeat the `var width...` line on the `fixWidth` handler, or put both that handler and the orientationchange binder within the first document ready function handler.

jQuery mobile does not include jQuery itself, which is a required library for the mobile version to work.

Anyway, I **highly recommend** to use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) as a good practice instead of doing this.

Comment: Can media query calculate width of screen

Comment: @AnkitaAgrawal Media queries are rules to implement on the CSS, so you can simply apply `width: 75%` without using JS